# Unsure of what formula to use

Tags: excel-formula

I have created a table - Column A is the customers short name and column B is their account number.  I need a formula that will look for the customers short name which is found in a text string (could be upper, lower or combination appearing somewhere in the cell) finding a match with the customers short name in the table returning the value of their customer number found in column b

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it well, you could do:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$7,D2)),0))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Mark, Your Awesome! Thank you

Comment: Thanks @CCsydney - I appreciate the feedback and glad it helps and welcome to Stack. Normally, the protocol on Stack is that if the work is good, up vote it.  If it is the answer, mark it as the answer.